# Can git be used to handle projects within a repo?

Tags: linux, git

I setup a git server on Debian and created a folder called git in `/srv/git/`.

Inside the folder, I'd like to divide my git projects by cloud hosted `cloud` and on-prem hosted `on-prem`. Inside of these two folders contain the hostname and it's specific files needed for deployment, redeployment, etc.

So a server that does apache on the cloud with a hostname like `webapp` will have a folder structure like `/srv/git/repos/cloud/webapp`.

Should the command `git init` be ran from the `cloud` folder or `webapp` folder?

Comment: I didnt follow your question. you have two repos, in which one is inside the other one,  if I understood correctly your repos dir has list of git repos? are those repos are submodule?

Comment: Sorry, it's `/srv/git/repos/cloud.git/webapp` or should I use `/srv/git/repos/cloud/webapp.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your setting up the bare repo.

As you mentioned in the question, you want to have separate git projects plural here so what I understood is you want to have more than one project under cloud directory.

## Method 1:

```
cloud
  |------->webapp  
  |------->something1
  |------->something2
```

Very straight way is doing `/srv/git/repos/cloud/webapp.git` here webapp is the git repo.

Setting up the webapp as git repo.

```
git init --bare /srv/git/repos/cloud/webapp.git
```

- `--bare`: for the bare repo you can skip this using on exisiting repo.
- Though init is not harmful to give on existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there

## Method 2:

```
cloud (git repo)
  |------->webapp     (submodule)
  |------->something1 (submodule)
  |------->something2 (submodule)
```

In another option where you can keep cloud as git repo and make webapp as submodule. That is repo inside the git repo.

You can choose what fits to you best.

I suggest to use two different repo, if your have plenty of submodules in one git repo it might be cumbersome at the start to keep track of things.

Comment: So when I need to have a few files from `/srv/git/repo/cloud/webapp/` I don't need to clone or copy the entire repository of non-relevant stuff to the new host if I use method 2?

Comment: If you need to access the file from git repo server then you will be having local copy on machine. If you dont want to clone the repo into your local copy you can particularly checkout the specific file, you dont have to clone the entire repo.  Sample command to get specific file from git repo `git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -x ` or just use  `wget ` it will do the job

Comment: I followed option 1 - it would be easier if I did need to clone and not bring in all the submodules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you should run `git init` from the cloud folder, giving webapp as the first argument, i.e. `git init webapp`.

That said, you could also create the webapp directory, change into it, and then run git: `mkdir webapp; cd webapp; git init;`  The end result will be exactly the same, but why bother?.